# I need lightweight Linux distro with VM support for an old processor

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, memory, graphics, lightweight

I have an old notebook with an i3-2350M (2 cores, 4 threads, and integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000) and 4 Gb RAM, and a decent SSD.
The mother does not supports more ram.

I only use it, mostly for web browsing and some light Visual Studio Code.

Originally it had Windows 7, browsed the web perfectly Ok, meanwhile also running virtual machines.

It updated automatically to Windows 10, which, after many non-consensual upgrades stopped supporting virtual machines, and became slower and slower, to the point it cannot even run youtube videos at 720 smoothly. A big problem is that it runs out of ram, which is shared to graphics.

I think that the end of support for VM is due to new security requirements.

So I want to replace the OS with Linux, to restore web performance, and virtual machines support.

I do not trust major distros like Ubuntu, because I had bad experiences with his automatic updates (on other machines). But I also would like a supported Linux distro.

Which distros are lightweight, and also supports VM on old processors?

Comment: [Linux Mint 21.1 Vera Xfce](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=304)

Comment: YouTube videos are now encoded in VP9 with which your CPU might struggle with regardless of the installed OS. Your CPU/iGPU doesn't have a VP9 hw decoder.

Comment: Choose any OS with a modest DE: https://itvision.altervista.org/linux-desktop-environments-system-usage.html - certainly not KDE or Gnome.

Comment: windows stopped supporting VMs? That sounds strange to questionable!

Comment: "I distrust major distros": you can turn off automatic updates on Ubuntu (as on any other distro). "Supported" actually means "offers updates", so I sense there's a bit of a conflict of wills here. (You generally want to have every security update, without even being asked about it. It's not like not getting security updates is really an acceptable option nowadays. In major distros like Ubuntu you can select to *only* get security updates. That's actually harder in smaller distros, where the limited workforce behind the distra can't "curate" a separate security update stream.)

Comment: @Marcus Müller It demands newer VT features that old processors do not have, so even old versions of virtual machines stopped working, because Windows refuse to pass VT capabilities availability to the VT machine, and it refuses to start.

Comment: Ah interesting.